# tstime and memory usage

Tags: osx, memory

So I am interested in measuring the high-water memory usage of a process. I would love to be able to use `tstime` but am having troubles figuring it out. Does it work in Unix? When I go to https://bitbucket.org/gsauthof/tstime to be able to download and use `tstime`, I was able to get it, but I keep encountering the error

```
cc -Wall -g -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE   -c -o tstime.o tstime.c

tstime.c:20:10: fatal error: 'linux/genetlink.h' file not found

#include <linux/genetlink.h>
        ^
1 error generated.

make: *** [tstime.o] Error 1
```

I'm having trouble understanding the error (will it not work because I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.4?) and figuring out how to fix it, so any help would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The headers in `/usr/include/linux` are provided by the Linux kernel. As noted in that projects README file the code depends on the "taskstats API", which is specific to the Linux kernel, I don't believe you'll get this running unmodified on OSX.